# How to modify the number of the rows in .csv file and plot them

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I read .csv file using this command

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', nrows=200)
```

I set the number of rows to 200. So it will only get the data for 200 rows. (200 rows x 1 column)

```
     data 
1    4.33 
2    6.98 
. 
. 
200  100.896
```

I want to plot these data however I would like to divide the number of rows by 50. (there will be 200 elements still but the numbers of the rows will be divided by 50).

```
         data 
0.02    4.33 
0.04    6.98 
. 
. 
4       100.896
```

I'm not sure how I would do that. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Just divide the index by 50.

Here an example :

```
import pandas as pd
import random

data = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : random.sample(range(300), 200)}, index = range(1,201))
data.index = data.index / 50

data
```

|  | col1 |
| --- | --- |
| 0.02 | 196 |
| 0.04 | 198 |
| 0.06 | 278 |
| 0.08 | 209 |
| 0.10 | 36 |
| ... | ... |
| 3.92 | 175 |
| 3.94 | 69 |
| 3.96 | 145 |
| 3.98 | 15 |
| 4.00 | 18 |